# NoSQL / Document DB / Cosmos DB - mapping of view data?

Tags: .net-core, automapper, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

Working on my first Microsoft NoSQL application and I am struggling with architecture. The CosmosDB tutorials are understandably but frustratingly rather basic. The ToDo app tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-dotnet-application) simply describes CRUD operations on a document of type Item - with very simple views and use of scaffolding.

My views are rather more complex and require additional information. I seem to have several options but I am unclear on the best approach. I could..

1. Make the JSON document fit my view. *I am uneasy about this due to mixing of view and 'domain' data - but this is from my relational DB viewpoint. Also when I POST I will need to account for updating of duplicate view data within the same document*.
2. Create a bunch of View Models and map these. *This would be my normal apporach but this seems to add a signifcant overhead just to add a few extra fields to what is a JSON object. I have not looked at AutoMapper for .NET Core - perhaps this would be a more attractive option.*
3. Use dynamics in some way. Microsoft has an example [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/f374cc601f4cf08d11c88f0c3fa7dcefaf7ecfe8/samples/code-samples/DocumentManagement/Program.cs#L331-L380).

Has anyone had a similar issue when moving to this new database - and could recommend an approach - and ideally point me to some online example/documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend you reading [Modeling document data for NoSQL databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data) firstly. For document with simple structure or infrequently accessed, I would choose option3 and option1, while for complex data, I would prefer to define my data models.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. I had read the article you recommended. Useful. So 'while for complex data, I would prefer to define my data models' is this option2? In which case I guess it is 'it depends'?

Comment: If there have complex relationships embed in a single document or cross multiple documents, I would define the view model for better readability, operability.